# Get byte array from Java.IO.File variable in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, java-io

I am creating a xamarin forms application that lets user pick multiple audio files from external storage. I have got success in picking multiple files, but whenever I try to read file content it gives me exception that 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'. I am using the following method to read bytes from audio file:

```
private byte[] GetPathToAudioFile(global::Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try
        {
            File file = new Java.IO.File(uri.ToString());

            string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(file.Path);

            byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return byteArray;
    }
```

It always gives me error. Please help me with this so that I can read file content as byte array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have external storage access? Look at PCL storage to handle things for you.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am new to xamarin development. I wasn't available to pick multiple items from PCL, so I implemented renderer, and from that renderer I need to send data back in form of byte array as I am using MessagingCenter to handle things for me.

Comment: https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Whats the value of the "path" is it just the directory ?     https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.IO.FileOutputStream/

Answer (score 1):

> whenever I try to read file content it gives me exception that 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'

The problem is that when you use `uri.ToString()` method to get the file path, the format is wrong. As a result, when the system use this path to search file, it will tell you  `DirectoryNotFoundException`, actually, the file path didn't exists.

For example, when you use `uri.ToString()`, your file path looks like this :

```
Path == /file:/storage/emulated/0/netease/cloudmusic/Music/love.MP3
//Not valid
```

**Solution :**

Use `uri.Path` instead, usage like this :

```
byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uri.Path);
```

Its file path ：

```
 uri.Path == /storage/emulated/0/netease/cloudmusic/Music/love.MP3
```

Now, it works fine.